Does a Robo Rally robot rotate when moving from Green to Blue belt?
In 30th Anniversary Robo Ralley (which I believe is the same rules as 2023 edition), Green Belts move after Blue Belts.

If you ride a green belt that merges into a Blue Belt, and the turn is Blue, would you be turned by the belt?

My reading of the rules is that you won't rotate, which feels broken. I think the junction needs a green turning arrow.

I had to double-check the 30th Anniversary rules (blue and green conveyors work slightly differently than the "express" and "normal" conveyors from the original game), but yes, blue conveyors first move twice, then green conveyors move once.
Page 13, however, clarifies how rotating conveyor belts work:

When a conveyor belt causes a robot to convey onto a curved conveyor space (during Board Element Activation), they will rotate 90 degrees in the direction of the curved arrow on the conveyor belt (left or right).

(Emphasis in the original)
I don't see any stipulation here that the curved arrow must be the same color; therefore a robot will rotate when moved by a green conveyor onto a blue curved arrow (even if that doesn't match your idea of how physical conveyors would work).

The easy way to remember the effect (and answer uncertainties) is that the same side of the robot that was "arrowside" (in the direction of the arrow) on the starting square winds up arrowside on the ending square.

Ah, you are correct, I hadn't read that. Thanks!
